# building python dictionary class

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I'm trying to write a hashing class where you can add and see if the item exists using Python's built-in dictionary. I tried this but seems to ignore the put method, but it is possible to check for existing item. Can anyone help me?

```
class Hashtable (object):
    def __init__(self):
        atom={}
        self.atom=atom

    def put(self ,name ,number):
        atom={}
        self.atom=atom
        self.name=name
        self.number=number
        self.atom[self.name]= self.number

    def get(self ,name):
        return self.atom[name]

    def __str__ (self):
        keysstring =str(self.atom[self.name])
        return keysstring
```

Comment: This isn't directly related to what you're asking about, but I don't think that `__str__` is going to be very useful.

Comment: At least at this point, your class currently doesn't really add much functionality beyond that already in a regular Python dictionary. For that reason you might want to just use a regular dictionary or perhaps derive your own specialized subclass of one using `dict` as the base class (instead of a generic `object`).

Comment: I know it does not add anything new to the dictionary in python . it happened to be a part of another program . using it as an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `put` method, you assign a new empty dictionary to `self.atom`, erasing whatever was already stored there.  Just do this:

```
def put(self, name, number):
    self.atom[name] = number
```

There's no need to assign `name` and `number` to `self.name` and `self.number`, since they will also be overwritten every time you call `put`.